# How to create dropzone upload when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to make dropzone.js with button click, not auto upload but when I click button submit, then the file is uploaded,
here's my code

```
$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
    url: SITE_URL + 'self_reimbursement/upload',
    autoQueue: false,
});

$('#submit').click(function(){           
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

the error displaying `Undefined index: file`

when not using submit or auto upload is success, but when I added a submit button is failed, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to prevent dropzone default.

I think it goes this way:

```
$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
url: SITE_URL + 'self_reimbursement/upload',
autoQueue: false,
});

$('#submit').click(function(){  
preventDefault();         
myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Try and replay. :)

Comment: the file is uploaded, but I cannot save to database, the file name can't get,
I use this code 
`$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetPath = getcwd() . '/assets/reimburse/';
$targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;`

Comment: Update your question. Include your form code, and also php file that process database insert.